# Statistics - correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, covariance

I have a statistics question and have calculated the part (a) answer. But I have no idea on part (b) as i have the no clue on $E(XY)$ to calculate the cov($X$.$Y$). I write to seek for advice on part (b). Please find below for the details and my calculation on part (a).

Let X and Y be random variables with $E(X|Y)=2Y$, Var($X$|$Y$)=$6Y$<sup>$2$</sup>, $E(Y)=7$, Var($Y$)$=10$.

(a) Find the mean and variance of X.
(b) Find the correlation coefficient between X and Y.

Ans for (a)
 
E(X)
 
=E(E(X|Y))
=E(2Y)
 
=2E(Y)
 
=14

Var(X)
 
= E(Var(X|Y))+Var(E(X|Y))
 
= E(6Y<sup>2</sup>)+Var(2Y)
 
= 6E(Y<sup>2</sup>)+4Var(Y)
= 6(Var(Y)+(E(Y))<sup>2</sup>)+4Var(Y)
= 6(10+7<sup>2</sup>)+4x10
= 394

Please help to advise the part (b) solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[Y\,\mathbb{E}[X|Y]]=2\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=2(10+7^2)=118$$
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=118-98=20$$